# How expose child element v-model as the vue component v-model

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I Was using a simple text area in my vue component.:

```
<input v-model="someRootProperty"/>
```

I would like to encapsulate this input inside another component, for instance

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>...</div>
        <input v-model="???"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I would like to use

```
<my-component v-model="someRootProperty" />
```

instead and them bypass this to the input inside the component.

What should I do inside the component to expose its input v-model as the component v-model?

Comment: Did you read the official documentation? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<input v-model="someRootProperty"/>
```

Is the same as (syntactic sugar):

```
<input :value="someRootProperty" @input="someRootProperty = $event.target.value"/>
```

That means that you could accept `value` as a prop in the component and emit `input` to achieve the same thing.

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['value']
}
```

And then use it like this.

```
<MyComponent v-model="someRootProperty"/>
```